# Full width container with fix width content. Sass, Bourbon Neat

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I wish to make my background full width, with a image or colour background filling the row. However, I would like the content to sit in the middle spanning the standard 12 cols dictated by neat.

Currently my structure is:

```
   <div class="container">
    <section id="section">
        <div class="left-col">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </section>
   </div>
```

With the relevant sass being:

```
.container
 +outer-container(100%)
 background-color: #fff
 padding: 40px 0

 #lead-text
  +span-columns(12)

  .left-col
   +span-columns(4)

  .right-col
   +span-columns(8)
```

This results in the container spanning the full width of the browser. But so does the inner section? I would like this to sit in the centre across the standard 12 cols?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your current HTML I would do the following in SCSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: pink;
}

#section {
  @include outer-container;
  background-color: #fff;
}
div.left-col {
  @include span-columns(4);
}
div.right-col {
  @include span-columns(8);
}
```

This makes the section the element neat treats as the `outer-container`, leaving the `.container` element to do it's natural thing of spanning the full browser window width, allowing you to add a background.

Comment: Hi all, I pull this together in the hope is explains what I am after better?

Comment: Hi did you mean to post a link?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right you want to do a "break-out-of-parent"

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="break-out">Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
//  use border-box to prevent padding from
//  being added to width (alway do this)    
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*,*:before,*:after { box-sizing: inherit; }


//  the container is aligned center with 
//  a maximum width of xxx (doesn't matter)
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px; 
}

//  breaking out of the container 
.break-out {
   //  set the width to full screen width    
   width: 100vw;

   //  use calc to pull content back to the center
   margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);

   //  to make the content re-align with the container
   //  use the reversed calc to set padding
   padding-left: calc(50vw - 50%);
}
```